# A beautiful and easy way of permutation with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, combinatorics

I want to share a better version of permutation with you.

Yesterday, when I was reading *Horowitz's Fundamentals of Data Structures In C++*, and I noticed that the result of the code, at page 32, in the book is not what I want.

For example, if I have an array of {'a', 'b', 'c'}, then the result it provides is:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cba
cab
```

Notice that the last two cases don't fit what I want: when 'c' is fixed, all the other letters at its right should start from a, with relative order, \$a \lt b \lt c \lt \ldots \lt z\$, so the result should be:

```
...
cab
cba
```

Here is my code, which corrects the order with two modified swaps:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printPermutation(char *a, const int k, const int m);
void swap2(char *a, const int l, const int r);
void swap3(char *a, const int l, const int r);

int main() {
    char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    printPermutation(&str[0], 0, sizeof(str)-1);
    return 0;
}

void printPermutation(char *a, const int k, const int m) {
    if (k == m) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            cout << a[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = k; i <= m; i++) {
            // the code in the book just use swap, but I change them.
            swap2(a, k, i); // here
            printPermutation(a, k+1, m);
            swap3(a, k, i); // and here
        }
    }
}

// swap2 will move the element at index r to l,
// by continuously swap with element at its left
void swap2(char *a, const int l, const int r) {
    for (int i = r; l < i; i--) {
        swap(a[i], a[i-1]);
    }
}

// The same concept with swap2, but from left to right
void swap3(char *a, const int l, const int r) {
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        swap(a[i], a[i+1]);
    }
}
```

How can I further simplify the code?

I like the idea that the author used recursion to make things beautifully simple. But to achieve the result I want as described above, I have to add two additional, a little bit similar, functions.

Comment: Oops, I just found that there is a phrase to describe the result I want: *lexicographically larger* permutation..., hope this help your understanding...

Comment: And the function `printPermutation` will print the range $$[k, m]$$, not $$[k, m)$$, sorry if this make you confused...

Comment: I wrote a series of articles on elegant ways to produce permutations in C#; you might find it interesting. It starts here: https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: @EricLippert: I was stuck at part4, last line of second snippet, about why the item inserted is n-1 not n, and finally realize that your permutation start from 0... Now I can moving forward...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simpler code would look something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "abcde";

    while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()))
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

If you wanted to do something on the same general order as a Python generator, you'd use C++'s new coroutine support. What's currently included is (by intent) very low-level, so you need a fair amount of infrastructure on top of it before it's easy to write a Python-like generator.

To keep from getting buried in details you probably don't care a lot about (right now) I'll use [Kenny Kerr's `Generator` class](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIBSAJgGY8AO2QAbZlgDU3fgGFMADwAOmYngC2mIQQCGogPRpiLAsMwzs3AAwBBPoJHipM2QDcdandovW7A4WISmNJyDARYCuxKBD629gFOwS5h%2BKgAdAixdrYEmOpKojq5IbIEAJ4qQjqakgAqWWHEzMgEksBaqkUkvtwA7ABCvpLDko3NrUrG6ngMmAD65SpDI32DtiMbo%2BEgIO6e3nK1kmhCYQBUpFvoO4pRpqhCc9HEFpLu4ub8a9k2myOTqGmswWFXMvAAbG1MAQ5sRoaxHqgAEZUTAtCAASmWf1W2L%2BIzhBARkjOBAQMxk33x0l6ABEeut8SkbspVBotLpRDsGMwGJV0HM9AB3HRlBiSYSEPB6OY8vladCYvEbXGM6nDQnE3F0ynKlY6uJqzbMkCKFRqTTaPTc3n8wWiEViyQAM2EMrl/KVRpVAz1f01xCENMGOq%2Bfpp9MNvyZ21NrItHOtIA9CvtjvFZTwmFEAvezEwECOJzCfEhqDJqix3v1VPVwzzSX4tKuOx06HQcIYTGdEHLCEruur/vhgeDfXpYaHEYZ0b%2BrlQeHQkgDj3ni69s82qs3PsjP2puXyhWKLkWWmqwWwyk7DDwDyy1Kvk0wXbvQlLpckOhFhAWxC8DDOiQ6gQE%2BN5vh%2BEKSGa4EPFWO41uGGxhEUeDIIKXaqAQEC3gAXpgqA9jBL63nBIQTs2ViXHwvBoIKP6tDMkhCOWozMEoSgkLkS7CMcJAmGY4qEZIZ5QkInREC8vC8Fik4IcORKjiaQHECKxDoC4YEkRB/DYBAxGvnBg7ydOUbUmuS7MEICBeOgoiYAKtyYNEb4btS251vWej5uRLYgOoqCuAWJrIKwcLaHMTkuQ8mKybWOIGvu%2BIWcu0IIMYQpzHgzpzM6Oh4PZirwe5vpThs2WSBADZpMIESYuRMjNrQxWeR5nnIbGhLpagmVRfcQg4bG7QxHItAWFV3mYBicVIfqe4lfNc3GXivLCMAkg2UIdnzKJjV%2BWabKWpyOxGAJ4lzJt20uACQI7aCPhyXil32SCKgbbZ9mrMxzCiKIzzTo9RpjC0Eq5P%2Bkl4m1fyrUI62EBJJBzMgRSYMAJBlL5JrCEozAwvD4OI7owDGdSMPrQ2r2Ns29RyaTt6w5I%2BDOs6qhaOwlO%2Bc8TM5SN8WbGTkiccIYO%2BUWDznCT%2BIC3CLPhewot8acMQQstU7PXdb3q6rJn410xCDdcIBCD9f0EMQCwYpIIDvVt9kQMbv3PC1CV87uM7UrrkkQOrHM%2B2elvW%2Br3sfRrU3hlDW6JeGnskNIEKoOaet8IMvD9G5%2BIR9S6tpJ2zCaEqgMmeVzqVdn6APAW02zcMmeeTdMyh5%2B9ezL52fN5XkvtcM6u%2BQ7psvLTXfDO3OdpRlWU5XlBUOQXrsZ1HZUEiOQakuSDCd5He7R2DeuSAnCNSSnafC5be1YPZuTa9SSKoKgoh74nENNo1EAx8QisllBfaVh/MRTrXCliQ90antb%2BxAMghw3m7My%2BIb53wfgfMAYAX5v1/p%2BMBltix/xMgAzYK5JBIIgKvJiICmx7wrMQGa/8F4mTFkrdBj8SBnHqlg8OpUi5L0UivE0w0XBWHGm3KYDdMRpAbFQnBNDqR0POAggmxAAC041MHi2wSVOegClKxjbB2EihFeyMOIMwqug8EqLRrqGb4eJUFIlRsIdO5j1EShLhAJB6tnaR0cRsfBfdnhQKWjAv42dc753EdHZxZcK6xTYZ4kYgjATCIxKPMk49sq5XyoVWe1dUpcO%2Bo7M2fjzFbynPgrWJjTJJWGKghU9ixzFOXrk/uG9xzuxGO0cSciIDt0pk3IRswA7hiDn7UEOxnRTCeL0gs7cq5Ggjs0gJYkD71TPpgPKP1eZ4jaYszZci0EQlPmQ8%2B0JPh822bvUs%2B85Ev1OZJXZ4J9nNkOZfQuGxrkkGgB0S5Ksv4UIDjbbavYKEQNtmHGZ7DqRgKBdtXuJtfFlLmRUhZOzzkGKuR8pOXyyw/MhmC/EFUIBkiYkgva5ysXUJid3EOvkIWlPJeQ/s4DgFkJ8fksp0CEVePqcQ9ecLJEjAAH6vP1u43BeK3HRKyWXF8ZtUBlEydQsx5TmmF0PAUFGJQzxVBqDTSwthBUuGFq8f8sMCxHFdMQMIlwjiFDCPBCOQpyT2UqmasIBDkFkOtQQYVOK/h0UzNmJczrlZHyaVHGhKrjyNlKKCTVwRtW%2BD1XIA1ullxeHaLQQsLo8DmoIJayQHrbXeskPa6eTqs0uqJe6nQNrsWOOST1PyohUDADQpFYgxh9Y0X6NgAA4gASQAHI0VCVOX1WYcyZuzcnKdPKt5hryKqk8cgNUXjqFkBNsgk3YBTca3gGbA25vzT0QtxbHUQEDa6vah7QWONHf6idn9g3PPxHWoUDam0ttUO2iANFe21GwAAJRsLUAA8v%2BodIbZ1FJsOGtVp5o0rrjbqtFT8N0HC3Ua9oAAWPdZac11DzVWz1R6%2BZ0RXMtGhwtJDqHygNAtfNJjCx7DRbgABWWQQgMPmDY%2B%2BaSw7NxmzKDW8MKlKqUbwFbbd7QIBUUkLQKw0yJG0oY9oJj0k%2BAsY0txmilw8DiIWtihVyMCDIAQJVE0fU3y3Ogl6xxymCCqd4Op9eWnpKXEwGke1RQokzpacPNQKnv1qe45xsaLmZJXxGAJoTU4ROv20BKCTIXpOXDkwptRWS7MOfU5p9j2mJR6fngq%2BFGwjMmbM7GCzDwrMgs3LgzLgXHO8BY853LrnoIeZsthYxfN4V4nq8x4LqbMCObC3xjYUXr3CdjnFxiiWhu7pk6l9xPolP%2Bfsw17LrHWu8B0wV0xBm8SldMwbFkdxLOsKgjVlb4Z%2Btqaay1njO32uea63txVRoJu1cLRsWLYm5vGuw4t%2BTy3EKLz84xjbTWcuPd2wU8pbKStFDKyduMZ2qsXchFd0HJlbuNea1tmHz3OveZ66GvcnAMSkC5JwFjnBSBCC4FYOnqAuCyCnanUYLA2BJAELQOnBBGcU8pwAaxACx3gaQAActBMPgl6JhprcuACcSuWNU64JhunDPOBM9ICzzgdOGAgCogLnXFPSBwFgDARAKBARKGnmQCgEA0D5AdygQosM/xWWF6QV0ogwZG4gHMYPVhKCU6RIL0gLujrAaEKIMokf8BwhaHgIKRuzfkG0NmSPVAACO%2BZiAJ84PwNIEu%2BdU60MAMkdBSDPlcMBlEaIBdB5D2HivsNq/0Drw31ELRKDB7mKH6gABFAvZR%2BC8Dk7wSX4vMPS96PLzDtBaBK/4LL2glB8B8kKEXoX7eq9IGapTs2GhBeU4Tv1dP8iUiNWQOz/otBcKSHkc6U6uNBLyIIOKa/4RRB4CRI1H/kiHfqnMnM/gAOosTyIgFHyP7yKKC5CnBvjf7Aa8CG5c7sB0CU7U60706R764KCS7gjyLgiYbHAe7rT4pNBCDC6WygT4A3L2D0CSCyB24O5xz8DNT85n4i4gD8BK5pBWD8AsYsZWByYq4sZK60AsYz7q6cCa6kDqBi5UTa66766G7G6kCm5M6U6W424mA4w5pO4u7272TEA14OSEAkBYFyG4GqHM5cBMFFqECmaEHEGkHkGpqVRmze4YjcFm7TSkD9htiqBt7U4KFKGiF4EZ7qGMCaHaF76i6Ya9BpC0Az4T4sby4T5WBWBq7U78Ba74FcD%2BE6HYFcBoHRFqHFFaE8GkBBTmpvggCYZAA%3D%3D%3D) (the first 173 lines, transplanted into a header). Using it, we get something like this:

```
#include "generator.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
generator<T> perm(T initial) {
    while (std::next_permutation(initial.begin(), initial.end()))
        co_yield initial;
}

int main() { 
    using namespace std::literals;
    for (auto const &i : perm("abcde"s))
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

As to your code, a few points jump out:

1. Don't use `std::endl`. It flushes the stream, which you almost never want. Just use `'\n'`. On the rare occasion that you do want to flush the stream, use `std::flush`.
2. The C library reserves most names that start with `str`, so it's probably better to avoid using that as a name.
3. `using namespace std;` is widely considered a problem except under a small number of rather unusual circumstances.
4. If you really want to do this (more) on your own, you might want to take a look at `std::rotate`, which can replace both your `swap2` and `swap3`. `std::rotate` will also typically be more efficient than your implementation.
5. `swap2` and `swap3` strike me as poor names. At first glance, it seems like `rotate_left` and `rotate_right` would probably be better names (but also see above).

Answer (score 7):

I find permutations both fun and fascinating, so this is pretty cool.

I was going to say most of what @Jerry Coffin said, so rather than repeat all that, I'll just point out a few things:

- Your `str` variable in `main()` looks a lot like a typical NUL-terminated C string, but isn't. It's even named `str` furthering the confusion. If a future developer were to call, say, `strlen()` on it, it would likely crash. I'd rename it.
- Your variable names are cryptic. What are `k` and `m` in `printPermutation()`? They're indexes into `a` (also a terrible name) for where to start and end the permutation. I suggest renaming them something like `startIndex` and `endIndex`.
- Likewise with `l` and `r` in `swap2()` and `swap3()`.
- As pointed out, `swap2()` and `swap3()` actually rotate rather than swap. Regardless of that, the names imply that they're doing something with 2 and 3 parameters, but they aren't. You should avoid just adding a number to an existing similar function to get a new name. This is an antipattern that persists in programming.

One way you could make this more useful is to make a templated function for permutations so that they work on containers of any type. (I guess that's what `std::permutation()` does - but it's always fun to learn on your own!)